# new file template in visual studio 2013

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012

Does anyone know how to add a new template to the File -> New -> File command in VS 2013?
Everything I can find about templates are either for a new project or a new item, none are for a new file.

I want to be able to select File -> New -> File, and see my template on the list.  I see a bunch of templates there but I can't find anywhere how to get my own there.

I created a new item template that is just my one file I am trying to add, but it only appears in the Add New Item dialog when you want to add items to a project.  None of my work is with projects it's all just individual files, so I don't use projects.

Answer (score 0):

Add your file to "*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\NewFileItems*".

I also tried adding it to "*C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\NewFileItems*" but that didnt work.